# Splitter.isParallel returns false? (Version 2.10.2)

Tags: scala, scala-collections

I have code that monitors the progress of a foreach method but needs to be able to detect whether the foreach loop will happen in parallel to choose the appropriate progress tracking algorithm. Spent time tracking down a bug and isolated it to this:

```
scala> Vector(1,2,3).iterator.isParallel
res11: Boolean = false
scala> Vector(1,2,3).isParallel
res12: Boolean = false
scala> Vector(1,2,3).par.isParallel
res13: Boolean = true
...

scala> Vector(1,2,3).par.splitter.isParallel
res13: Boolean = false
scala> Vector(1,2,3).par.iterator.isParallel
res14: Boolean = false
```

Is this a bug or do I misunderstand the function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the `isParallel` method is defined in the TraversableOps class, which you get from various of the collection classes via an implicit conversion. The relevant source snippet (from scala/collection/parallel/package.scala) is:

```
implicit def traversable2ops[T](t: scala.collection.GenTraversableOnce[T]) = new TraversableOps[T] {
  def isParallel = t.isInstanceOf[Parallel]
  ...
}
```

As can be seen from this, a class needs to extend the `Parallel` marker trait to return true from this method. As it turns out, the various parallelised collections do this, but their iterators don't. That is, it appears that `Parallel` has only been used to mark the actual collections, not their helpers. I don't know whether that is as intended or if it could be argued to be an oversight.